# Jenkins job with batch stage has a zombie environment variable

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have a python command line program that can retrieve passwords for me.
I can run it from the command line and get the passwords.
Example command:

```
passwordmanpro_cli javaprops OpenWeatherMap_DEV
```

The response comes back fine.

I have the Jenkins agent installed on the machine. I have a "Execute Windows Batch Command" step which calls exactly the same commandline.

This USED to work without an issue. A month ago it stopped working. With an error:

```
ERROR Success not returned from passwordmanagerpro
Using URL - https://icsecpws.cc.ic.ac.uk:443/restapi/json/v1/resources (AUTHTOKEN ommitted - 36)
ResponseCode - 200
resJSON - {'operation': {'name': 'Authentication', 'result': {'status': 'Failed', 'message': 'User is not allowed to access from this host'}}}
IP Being used to send message might be: 155.198.31.184
```

Something is different from how this request is sent via a windows terminal and how it is sent from a windows batch step in Jenkins.

I have verified the windows batch command is being run as a correct user.
I have verified the username and password credentials being passed are the same
I have verified the source IP by adding debug lines in python.

The password manager we are using has an API user setup and you enter an IP address the API is allowed to be called from. Apparently the restriction is not done on source IP but a reverse hostname lookup.

Can anyone give me advice on how to debug this further?

### Update 1

More debugging has revealed that the cause is the environment is being set wrong. The host machine is windows 10. I have an environment variable called PASSMANCLI_AUTHTOKEN and another called PASSMANCLI_URL

In control panel I am setting both variables system wide. NOT for a particular user.
What is really strange is that the PASSMANCLI_URL is changing and being picked up ok, but the PASSMANCLI_AUTHTOKEN variable is not. I have added a "set" windows batch command in the config and I have confirmed that the PASSMANCLI_AUTHTOKEN value is NOT coming from the system setting but somewhere else. I am wondering if Jenkins does anything special with this.

BTW: I have also used the whoami command as part of the project config and confirmed Jenkins is running as the same user.

## Update 2

I have gone through the entire windows registery and looked at all Environment entries and deleted PASSMANCLI_AUTHTOKEN. I have confirmed it is not in the environment console. I have restarted the Jenkins agent and the entire server. I then run my jenkins job with a single command "Set" and it reads back the OLD value of the token!

## update 3

I have created a brand new Jenkins job with 1 step which is the windows batch command. It simply has "set" so displays the environment variables. I can see PASSMANCLI_AUTHTOKEN is still being set even though I have completely wiped it from the machine.

## update 4

I thought it might be something to do with the way the Jenkins runner uses JAVA. (Our Jenkins runner is using Java 8 32 bit). I wrote a Java program which runs

```
processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "set");
```

and outputs the result.
I checked the output and the variable is NOT set, as expected.
I still don't know where this variable is coming from when executed via Jenkins.